# Heat pump dryer circuit board issue

Tags: pcb, voltage-regulator, repair

My heat pump clothes dryer recently stopped condensing altogether. The drum still gets hot, but no water is being drawn out of the clothes, suggesting the condenser is not getting cold enough to condense the moisture into the water drain tray.

I opened up the dryer and inspected it. All seems to be operational, however, the compressor sounds like it is trying to start but it never actually starts running.

I found a control board which I removed and found some signs of damage on two components, as per attached photos.

It seems that the voltage regulator (117-33 TH HAY) between the 16 V 100 µF and 220 µF capacitors is damaged, as well as the 51 kΩ ±5% resistor.

Where I to get these two components replaced, do you think this would solve the issue, is there anything else that sticks out in the photos attached that could be a root cause to these two components failing?

[image: dryer circuit board front]

[image: dryer circuit board bsck]

Comment: what are those two components? ... what is their function in the circuit? ... please provide a schematic diagram of the circuit

Comment: Nothing there looks obviously damaged to me. If the large capacitors EC4, 6, and ? are bulging that could be an indicator, but it's hard to tell from that angle.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that the voltage regulator (117-33 TH HAY) between the 16 V 100 µF and 220 µF capacitors is damaged

How do you know that? Did you measure its input and output? It doesn't look damaged. And if there's input but no output, is the part hot? It may be in thermal shutdown due to a shorted output. These parts have protection in overload situations, so just because the load is shorted doesn't mean *necessarily* that the part has failed. You can cut a trace to disconnect the load and see if it recovers.

> as well as the 51 kΩ ±5% resistor.

That resistor looks perfectly normal to me. You'd need to measure it with one leg out of circuit to check if it's actually bad.

---

All that you're showing so far is some resin soldering flux covering parts and/or solder joints. You can clean if off with alcohol and some cotton swabs.